# How to change the woocommerce template loop_product_link_open function of the woocommerce store front?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, storefront

When I click on the product on the category page, I want it to be sent to `addtocart` and not to the `product` page.

I know this function is responsible for this:
`woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open`

But I can not find this function in the store front source code.

This `wc-template-functions.php` file does not exist in my wordpress version.
I have this `storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php` file,
but the function is not there.

Can you help me?

Comment: I removed it by mistake

Comment: Hi friend, I'm in Brazil and I speak Portuguese. my english is bad I'm using google translator. Forgive me for the mistake?
Can you do the editing for me that this time I approve?
thank you.

Comment: Just edited. Please check again.